# Nilpotent residual subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, nilpotent-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\gamma_{\infty}(G)$ be the limit of the lower central series: $\gamma_1(G)=G$ and for all $i\ge 1, \gamma_{i+1}(G)=[\gamma_i(G),G]$ ? It can be shown that $\gamma_{\infty}(G)$ is  the nilpotent residual subgroup of $G$ i.e. for $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$, $G/N$ is nilpotent if and only if $\gamma_{\infty}(G)\le N$.

Is it true that
$$
\gamma_{\infty}(G)=\bigcap\limits_{p\ prime} O^p(G) ?
$$

Since 1/ for every prime $p$, $G/O^p(G)$ is a $p-$group hence nilpotent and 2/  for any $A,B$ normal subgroups of $G$, if $G/A$ and $G/B$ are nilpotent, then $G/A\cap B$ is nilpotent, it follows that 
$$
\gamma_{\infty}(G)\le \bigcap\limits_{p\ prime} O^p(G) 
$$
I don't know how to prove the converse inclusion and I tend to think it does not hold. 
However I found this is true when $G$ is nilpotent i.e. $\gamma_{\infty}(G)=1$. Indeed, $G$ is then the direct product of its Sylow subgroups. It follows that $O^p(G)$ is the product of all $Q\in Syl(G)$ such that $p \nmid |Q|$, for all primes $p$. Therefore, $\bigcap\limits_{p\ prime}O^p(G)=1$.

Comment: Since it is true when $G$ is nilpotent, it is true in $G/\gamma_\infty(G)$, which immediately implies that it is true in general.

Comment: Thanks Derek. I actually do not know how to prove that it is immediately true in general. I have $1=\gamma_{\infty}(G/\gamma_{\infty}(G))=\bigcap\limits_{p\ prime}O^p(G/\gamma_{\infty}(G))$. Then I can think of $O^p(G/\gamma_{\infty}(G)) \le O^p(G)\gamma_{\infty}(G)/\gamma_{\infty}(G)$ but not sure how to proceed further from there.

Comment: Let $O^p(G/\gamma_\infty(G)) = K/\gamma_\infty(G)$. Then $G/K$ is a $p$-group, so $O^p(G) \le K$. So your final inequality is an equality.  (We have $\gamma_\infty(G) \le O^p(G)$ by the way.)

Comment: Thanks very much, it is very clear.

Comment: The nilpotent residual $\gamma_\infty(G)$ is 'dual' to the nilpotent radical $F(G)$, which is usually called the Fitting subgroup. Keeping a well-known formula $F(G) = \langle\, O_p(G) \mid p \text{ : prime} \,\rangle$ in mind, perhaps you should have thought it must hold :)